# React Native Firebase v4.0 - Notification Module

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-firebase

I just installed react-native-firebase v4.0 and I'm trying to detect when someone opens a notification that I sent from google console.

But when I put the example from documentation into my code, I get

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected : (Fatal)

at "action"

What am I missing here? I never used this kind of syntax before.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen: NotificationOpen => {
            // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            // Get information about the notification that was opened
            const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to put notificationOpen: NotificationOpen around parenthesis.

```
(notificationOpen: NotificationOpen)
```

Comment: Hello, can you check this question please @R.Favero

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification