# Navigate to screen after opening a notification?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm using Firebase cloud functions to send a remote notification to a specific device I got his FCM Token, and I receive it and works very well,

Here is my code to send a notification by Cloud functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://-----.firebaseio.com"
});
exports.sendPushR = functions.database
  .ref("/request/{pid}/orders/{orderid}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const registrationTokens = snapshot.val().token;
    const event = context.params;
    const afterData = snapshot.val();
    const username = snapshot.val().username;

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "New Order",
        body: `You received a new order from ${username} check it now! `,
        sound: "default",
        icon: "default"
      }
    };

    try {
      const response = await admin
        .messaging()
        .sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload);
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    }
    return null;
  });
```

**And in the Home screen App**

```
  async componentDidMount() {
//BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backPressed);

this.notificationInitListener = await firebase
  .notifications()
  .getInitialNotification()
  .then(notificationOpen => {
    if (notificationOpen) {
      console.log(notificationOpen);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Notifications");
      }, 5000);
      console.log("1---OPEND");
      firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
      console.log("1---OPEND-After");
    }
  });
this.removeNotificationOpenedListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
    // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
    // const action = notificationOpen.action;
    // Get information about the notification that was opened
    // const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    if (notificationOpen) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Notifications");
      console.log("OPEND");
      firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
      console.log("OPEND-After");
    }
  });
 }
```

**Route**

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Home",
        headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
        headerRight: (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Notifications")}
            style={{ margin: 10 }}
          >
            <Icon name="ios-notifications" size={28} color="#1DA1F2" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })
    },
    MapScreen: {
      screen: MapScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Map"
      }
    },
    ProviderProfile: {
      screen: ProviderProfile
    },
    GalleryDetails: {
      screen: GalleryDetails,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Gallery Details"
      }
    },
    Order: {
      screen: Order,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Order"
      }
    },

    Favorites: {
      screen: UserFavorites,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "My Favorites!",
        headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
      })
    },
    Notifications: {
      screen: Notifications,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Notifications"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions
  }
);
```

Now I have two issues:

1. I think that's in the first function **getInitialNotification** that's at the first time I open the app without clicking on any notification it navigates me to Notifications Screen for a two or three second and get me back to the home, and
2. when I click the notification I received "when app is closing 'it's not in background '*Killing*' "!, just stuck in the **Home screen** not navigate me to **notifications screen**
   OR Navigate me I think for 2 seconds and get me back to Home Screen,

But the under function "**onNotificationOpened**" works very well when the app is still in the background

**Demo**
https://vimeo.com/350006721

Answer (score 1):

You don't have explained what you expected.. but I think you don't want to start with that notification-screen, but with the Home-Screen.

For this, you can use the `initialRouteName` as second parameter for your `createStackNavigator` method (see example at the very bottom of this Page: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

Give it a try, and if solved, go hunt for the second issue (I prefer to solve issues Step by Step)

Comment: First Issue is Solve with "initialRouteName ",  I think the second issue when I receive a notification "when app killed" and click to open it, it's opened very well and navigate me to "Notifications Screen" But in every time after I open the app without click to any notification it navigates me to "Notifications Screen", SO How can I remove the previous notification "remove the listener in **getInitialNotification** " @suther ?

Comment: the getInitialNotification method returns an object with notification data if the app was opened by clicking a notification and returns null if the app was opened by another method. In your code,
`if (notificationOpen){
  //navigate to notifications screen   
} else {
  //navigate to home screen
}`

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle navigation on notification opening is to handle them in a splash screen. this will give you more flexibility. just check if the app is opened by notification, in `componentDidMount`, And navigate to the desired screen. you can use  `createSwitchNavigator` to prevent android back button and ios gesture, from going back to the splash screen.

> I think the second issue when I receive a notification "when app killed" and click to open it, it's opened very well and navigate me to "Notifications Screen" But in every time after I open the app without click to any notification it navigates me to "Notifications Screen", SO How can I remove the previous notification "remove the listener in getInitialNotification "

To solve this issue you have to save the `messageId`/`notificationId` in `AsyncStorage` after processing the notification and before navigating to the new screen. And just before processing the notification you can check if that notification is already processed.

the steps you have to take:

1- check if the `notificationId` is processed before ( this can be an `AsyncStorage` call).

2- if processed: clear  `AsyncStorage`, 'cause we don't need it anymore

3- if not: add the `notificationId` to AsyncStorage and navigate to the new screen